# How often do AWS EC2 instances' disks become corrupt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We all know the textbook says to have a database with replication to reduce chance of losing your data. While having database replication still doesn't theoretically give you zero chance of losing your data (all instances get corrupt at once or burn in fire), it does reduce it significantly.

But what is the chance if you have your data only on your EC2 disk it gets lost due to a corrupt disk to begin with? And what are AWS guarantees for that? Also, any stories you can share?

Thank you

Comment: this question is about database on ec2 or data stored on ec2?

Comment: Both, as a disk failure will affect both of them.

Comment: Then go for a higgle managed resource which ensure HA like aurora

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it's not an answer to my question.